# Erro ao restaurar pacotes nuget, projeto UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget

Tenho um projeto **Xamarin UWP**, e ao fazer o `build` do projeto, acontece uma série de ***erros*** desse tipo:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     System.Collections.Concurrent 4.0.10 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).            0    Error      System.AppContext 4.0.0 is
>   not compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-arm).            0
>   Error     System.Reflection 4.0.10 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64).            0
>   Error     System.IO.Compression.ZipFile 4.0.0 is not compatible with
>   UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).            0    Error      Autofac 3.5.2 is not
>   compatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x64-aot).            0    Error      Cannot
>   resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file
>   'System.Runtime.dll'  InfinitusApp.UWP    C:\Workspace\AppGestor\InfinitusApp\InfinitusApp\InfinitusApp.UWP\InfinitusApp.UWP.csproj
>   Error     Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     InfinitusApp.UWP

Pelo que eu pesquisei é algum erro com o nuget, já fiz esses seguintes passos, que não resolver:

- Intalar e desinstalar o nuget.
- Excluir a pasta packages e fazer o build de novo.
- Atualizar o SDK e o xamarin.

Answer (score -1):

Tive o mesmo problema, então segui esses passos para soluciona-lo:

1. Faça atualização pelo Nuget do
   **Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform** para a versão **5.2.2**.
2. Em seguida logo apos a instalação dos pacotes click com o botão
   direito do mouse e faça um novo build e deploy.

Ps: *Talvez seja necessário restartar o Visual Studio.*